# How to find out if an instance of my .app is already running or not?

Tags: macos, cocoa, multiple-instances, .app

My app is getting installed in the Application folder. But I can copy this .app file and paste it on my desktop. When I try to run this .app file on my desktop, two instances are running on my system. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could by many ways,

The first way that hit my mind is to look at `runningApplications` in `NSWorkspace`. This returns an NSArray containing a dictionary for each launched application. You can loop through the array to see if the app you are looking for is already running.

```
NSMutableArray *applications=[NSMutableArray new];    
[applications addObjectsFromArray:[[NSWorkspace new] runningApplications]];
NSLog(@"--> %@",applications);
```

Comment: thanks :) even this code works  - if ([[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]] count] > 1)