# how to get windows of NSRunningApplication

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication, nsworkspace, nsrunningapplication

I want to get the window list for a running application.
I can get the running application list from `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]`, but the window list is only available on `NSApplication`.
Is there some way to convert from `NSRunningApplication` to `NSApplication`, or some way to get the window list more directly?

Comment: Here is the same question, already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107657/mac-cocoa-getting-a-list-of-windows-using-accessibility-api

Comment: Even here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759688/how-to-find-out-if-an-instance-of-my-app-is-already-running-or-not/13759928#13759928

Comment: Widow list more directly means?

Comment: thanks. i'll check those two, then come back if i need something.

Answer (score 10):

You need to look at the CoreGraphics call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`.

You call it like this

```
    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
```

and then iterate over the array of window information, find the ones that are from the application you're interested in, and do what you want with it.

Comment: Hey Ken! That's a good answer/hint, but it still doesn't tell how to get the `CG/NSWindow` ;-) `NSRunningApplication` doesn't provide windows/window number and I'm crashing (probably doing something wrong) when trying to get the `NS/CGWindow` with my `CGWindowID` obtained with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`

Comment: That's because you can't create an NSWindow for another application. As far as getting the windows for a specific application, you can examine and compare the value of the `kCGWindowOwnerPID` key to the `processIdentifier` property of `NSRunningApplication`.